# How can I get other branches than "master" to show in my package explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

So I am really new to this so please execuse any incorrect terminology..
I am part of a private repository for a software project on Github..I imported the Git-project to eclipse using the URL of the repository, my problem is, only the master branch shows in my package explorer..but other participants created other branches with their code..how can I get those other branches to show so I can check the code/eventually run the program?
As you can see in the picture There are two branches showing in Remote tracking but not in Local..?[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwhXN.png)

Comment: Once you have the repo cloned, use `git switch` to change to a given branch. Git sends all branches along with master, it's fully distributed.

Comment: @elliottFrisch the 'switch' git command doesn't exist......

Comment: @Philippe Sorry, "checkout"... and OP is using eclipse, so [right click, Team, Switch To...](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Checking_out_an_existing_Branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the local branch corresponding to the remotes that you fetched when cloning and then check out them. You could do that in the same time with one command:

```
  git checkout NameOfTheRemote
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the OP wants a solution using Eclipse, as that's the only environment they've described so far.

In that case, you probably need to right-click on the repository in the "Git Repositories" view and select "Fetch" (local may not have all of the branches yet), and then right-click again and select "Switch to".  The branch you need may be in that list (not "New Branch"), otherwise you may have to click "Other" and select the branch in the "Remote Tracking" section (assuming it's not in "Local").